# Can a controller use the same instance of command from a controller it extends?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have multiple SimpleFormController controllers. One controller contains a command object used to filter results in the other controllers. I seem to be missing something simple, but I can't seem to find a way to use the same instance of the command object in the other controllers.

My setup is such that this main controller, let's call it RootController extends SimpleFormController, and the rest of the controllers extend RootController. The idea was that the command object is stored in one place - RootController and the controllers that extend it reuse the same object. However, it doesn't seem to be working that way, other controllers seem to have their own copy of the command object.

Comment: What do you mean by command object?

Comment: Form backing object, command class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form backing objects are just normal Pojos, so you can inherit it form each other.

```
public class BaseCommand {
  ...
}

public class MoreCommand extends BaseComman {
  ...
}
```

May you just forget the "update" the `commandClass` in your Controller Subclasses.

*Anyway: notice that SimpleFormController is deprecated in Spring 3.0. Instead the Annotation Style is preferred.*

---

Update: One INSTANCE of an command object, can be handled by only one INSTANCE of an Controller. So you can subclass the Controller (don't miss to call `super`), but you can not have two instances of the controller and hope that both are invoked.

Comment: I don't want to instantiate a new object, I want to use the exact same object as in the parent controller.

Also, I'm using Spring 2.0.8, so Annotation style is not available.

Comment: So "inherit" is may a miss leading term. But anyway, what is the problem. You do not need to do anything. Just set the same commandClass in both controllers. Or did you mixed the concepts of inheritance and instances?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I want to use the same instance of the command object. I edited the original question.

Comment: eagerMoose: I have extended my answer. Hopefully it covers now what you try.